# Enforcing strong passwords in Kohana Auth

Tags: regex, passwords, kohana, kohana-3.3, kohana-auth

I am trying to enforce strong(er) passwords in my Kohana application using Auth, by using the following regex to require at least one upper case letter, one lower case, one number, one non-alphanum (special character), and a minimum of 8 characters.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{8,}$
```

The regex is working, as can be seen on [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/bApSA7eWQ3). Here's the code I'm using in Kohana's `Model_Auth_User`, which extends `ORM`.

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        'password' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('min_length', array(':value', 8)),
            array('regex', array(':value', '/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{8,}$/'))
        )
    );
}
```

However, when creating  a new user account, or changing the password of an existing one, this regex seems to be completely ignored.  The `min_length` from the line above is working fine though!

It will stop me from using `test` as a password because it's less than 8 characters, but `testing123` doesn't give any sort of error message.

Any ideas why this is happening and a way around it?

Comment: You store password as hash? If I remember ORM rules are apply for database values, not for REQUEST values.

Comment: @bato3 Yes the password is hashed. The validation for the password is run on the POST values before encryption though.

Comment: I know this. I'm trying explain why up code don't work.  `save` without extra validation use internal values, ant this was hashed on `set` method. So you must use extra validation initialized raw (POST) values. https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#filters, [#set](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#save), [#create](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#create)

Comment: I have updated my question and answer to make it more clear. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - you have to add the regex to the `get_password_validation` function (in the same Model) or it doesn't output any error message.

```
public static function get_password_validation($values) {
    return Validation::factory($values)
        ->rule('password', 'min_length', array(':value', 8))
        ->rule('password', 'regex', array(':value', '/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{8,}$/'))
        ->rule('password_confirm', 'matches', array(':validation', ':field', 'password'));
}
```

If added, the regex in the `rules()` function needs to be removed or it's not possible to login as it runs the regex check on the hashed string, which doesn't contain any special characters.

Hope this helps someone.